# How to invoke a prototype function within same object?

Tags: javascript, closures

I have the following javascript code.

```
var Test = function(){



    $("#"+elementId).click(function(){
        // How to call Test.callbackTest here?
    });

}

Test.prototype.callbackTest = function(){
    //code
}
```

If I want to call callbackTest() in clicking event, do I have to use this.callbackTest()?

or is there any better ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `callbackTest` private:

```
var Test = function(){
   function callbackTest(){
      //code
   }

   $("#"+elementId).click(callBackTest);
};
```

Otherwise it should be

```
var Test = function(){
   var me = this;
   $("#"+elementId).click(function(){
        me.callbackTest();
   });
};
```

Comment: how do you ensure that this is bound to Test ?

Comment: :) Then its same as proposed by me : but i would rather use 'that' instead of 'me' , its more standard across js guys

Comment: @Kooilnc // Thank you for your input. I have a question. Is it safe to use Test.callbackTest() instead? Just confirmed it works.

Comment: Yep, it is. But I offer a private function with it.

Comment: @Moon: you can call `Test.callbackTest`, but I would advise against it. I think the private function is a clearer solution 'scopewise'.

Comment: @Kooilnc // Yes, I agree. Thanks!!

Comment: Am I right in thinking that using 'this' inside Test will only work if you call Test() as a constructor, i.e., `var x = new Test();` as compared to just `Test();`?

Comment: @n6: yes, you're right. If you call Test using the `new` keyword, that creates an instance of `Test` with a proper `this`. Just `Test()` would execute it as a regular function.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use from click function , this.callbackTest() wont work as this will be bound to window object and not your functions. There are various ways to do so .. one quick one

```
    var Test = function(){

       var that = this

        $("#"+elementId).click(function(){
            // How to call Test.callbackTest here?
             that.callbackTest();
        });

    }

    Test.prototype.callbackTest = function(){


  //code
}
```

jquery also provides a [proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) solution , i recommend you check it out. if you use it your code will be like

```
  var Test = function(){

        $.proxy(this.callbackTest,this) // This ensures that wheneven callbackTest is called , 'this' inside callbackTest will be bound to current object , in this case Test 
        $("#"+elementId).click(function(){
            //AND THEN YOU CAN USE THIS here 
             this.callbackTest();
        });

    }

    Test.prototype.callbackTest = function(){


  //code
}
```

Comment: @Moon, my pleasure : please also see modified reply.

Comment: // That proxy looks really interesting. Thanks a lot!!